# EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, equals, lombok

I use Project Lombok with Eclipse and I could compile the following class.

Now I'd like to exclude one field from the hash and equals methods by using the annotation `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` like [shown in the Lombok's documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode).

Unfortunately this doesn't compile. Why?

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@MappedSuperclass
public class Foo extends Bar implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 36364364363634634;

  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "PKGenerator", strategy = "com.project.utils.PrimaryKeyGenerator")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "PKGenerator")
  @Column(name = "guid")
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  private String id;

  @NotNull
  private String code;

  //...other fields omitted
}
```

The compile error I get is:

```
EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude cannot be resolved to a type
```

Disregarding which fields the annotation is applied to and the use of `callSuper=true` or `false`

Environment is:

```
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
..
Lombok v1.18.0 "Envious Ferret" is installed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you need Lombok 1.16.22 or higher, but which Lombok are you really using? (see below)

---

I found out the issue lied in a mismatch of the Lombok version used by the Lombok Eclipse plugin (up to date) and the one of the maven dependency (older).

If you will, spring boot is to "blame", since the project was set up with the [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) and the dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` sets the lombok version property to 1.16.20 at the time of writing.

In such a scenario, the version of in the effective pom wins against the version of the IDE plugin and as we can read from [The Lombok documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode):

> Prior to lombok 1.16.22, inclusion/exclusion could be done with the `of` and `exclude` parameters of the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation.
>   This old-style inclusion mechanism is still supported but will be
>   deprecated in the future.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed as of Spring Boot 1.5.14 and Spring Boot 2.0.3. These new versions include Lombok versions >= 1.16.22.
see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.14.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions
see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Answer (score 0):

Did you also update the dependency in your build file?

Comment: Yes, but I found out what's the issue: the project was set up with the start.spring.io and the dependency spring-boot-starter-web sets the lombok version property to 1.16.20. The Lombok documentation (https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) says _Prior to lombok 1.16.22, inclusion/exclusion could be done with the of and exclude parameters of the @EqualsAndHashCode annotation. This old-style inclusion mechanism is still supported but will be deprecated in the future._

Comment: I am not sure how the Eclipse plugin works but clearly the version in the effective pom won against the plugin.. Hopefully that is not going to cause further troubles!

Comment: Can you answer your own question? I found your question and answer useful.